# fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl

Tags: ember-cli, archlinux

I am using archlinx and installed ember-cli.
On `ember serve` I am recieving the following message:

```
A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1452004013: inotify-add-watch(/home/cristian/projects/transport-company/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io-pure/node_modules/socket.io-client-pure/node_modules/engine.io-client-pure/node_modules/parseuri/node_modules/better-assert/node_modules/callsite) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is usually good to check whether the piece of software that is complaining should actually use that much resources.

Just for the sake of testing, you could try `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=…` with some higher number than what it is right now (`sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches` to get the current value).

If you find the right value, set it permanently on a `/etc/sysctl.d/` file.

Comment: also this could be useful: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit

Answer (score 11):

Official documentation says:

If you’ve encountered this state it means that your kernel was unable to watch a dir in one or more of the roots you’ve asked it to watch. This particular condition is considered non-recoverable by Watchman on the basis that nothing that the Watchman service can do can guarantee that the root cause is resolved, and while the system is in this state, Watchman cannot guarantee that it can respond with the correct results that its clients depend upon. We consider ourselves poisoned and will fail all requests for all watches (not just the watch that it triggered on) until the process is restarted.
There are two primary reasons that this can trigger:

- The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached or
  the kernel failed to allocate a needed resource
- Insufficient kernel memory was available

You can increase max_user_watches:

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

If you changed limits, but still get the same error,- restart the watchman process(since 4.6):

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#i-39-ve-changed-my-limits-how-can-i-clear-the-error

Answer (score -1):

Used:

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: It's a somewhat horrifying way to poke the number 999999 into the kernel values that control how many inotify events can be queued at a time, how many inotify instances a user can run, and how many inotify watches a user can set up.  That many watches will use up a lot of unswappable kernel memory.